# stringWithFormat and % not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

i have this string

```
 NSString *jsonString = @"http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-31%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A721%7D";
 NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

the output is 

http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-31%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A721%7D
```

when i use

```
 NSString *linkId = @"448";//not a constant value only for example 
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-31%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A%@%7D",linkId];

 the output is 

http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=7                 37040ate23A222㿠                 37040isplay23A0x1.21800000507cp-1027ll27D&action=showMatches&params=7                     –ompetition_id23A(null)      0
```

as you see not the same.My question is how to use stringWithFormat to get this result:

```
  http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-31%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A448%7D
```

so the value (721) just at the and is replaced by (448)
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way of looking at it is that the thing you're giving it as a format string is really data, not purely a format.

To be safe from those spurious conversions, you'd want:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-31%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A",linkId, @"%7D"];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because all those `%` characters inside your format string are being potentially used to used the format arguments, much like `%@` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for details).

This can be seen (for one instance) where:

```
callback_params=%7B%22date
```

is transformed into:

```
callback_params=7                 37040ate
```

In that case, I'm not sure what the `%7B` is doing since it's not a valid format specifier, but the `%22date` is resulting in a 22-character decimal value, from `%22d`, followed by the literal `ate`.

You need to use `%%` in your format string if you want a single `%` in the output string.